# Audio Channel change/swap automatically

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, alsa

I am working with digital TV in Linux platform. Currently I am facing with one issue in audio. When I give stereo audio to

```
  snd_pcm_write_i
```

Function and after long time running the audio channels get swapped. That is, right channel audio hearing in Left channel and Left in Right. I dumped the PCM  data in to a file before giving to alsa in issue case and played using 'aplay' and audio is good.So I think the PCM data is OK.  In my system,'AK4643' audio codec device is used. Does any one faces this issue? If so please help me.

Comment: Either your DMA/I²S controller or its driver is buggy.

Comment: CL, Thanks . Now I too think so... But need to confirm it..

Comment: @CL. Its actually a bug in I2S driver. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was associated with the I2S driver .
Fixed the issue with updated driver from chip vendor.